# How does Leeloo know Vito Cornelius' name?

Tags: the-fifth-element

I saw it in French but if I remember correctly during the fog scene in the Fifth Element:

> KORBEN: Are you OK?
>
> LEELOO: Priest...
>
> KORBEN: Priest?  You need a doctor...
>
> LEELOO: Priest! Vito... Cornelius! (faints)

**How does she know that the priest of this time period is Vito?**

I don't know how she got time to investigate on "who is the priest in this age?" while running on rooftops and taxi driving, or maybe the priest order has rolling names...

Comment: She has genetic memory and presumably the priesthood on Earth have been in semi-regular contact with the Mondoshawans over the intervening centuries. That would explain their (and her) knowledge.

Comment: Maybe it's just customary for the priesthood to be led by a guy named Vito Cornelius, and every head priest assumes that name upon promotion to the job.  Like the Pope or the various kings and queens of England, who choose a new name upon taking the title (only these guys always use the same name.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously Leloo is being rebuilt (I'd say more like cloned, but this is somewhat murky waters in the movie) from recovered remains from the Mondoshawans' craft.

Since she is very advanced life form:

> MACTILBURGH: This cell is like a huge library. It has infinite genetic
>   knowledge stored inside. Almost like it was...engineered.

...it stands to reason that this genetic knowledge included priest's name.

Comment: As well as her knowledge of the "ancient language" and anything else she's able to do before she starts absorbing wikipedia at Vito's place.

Comment: Sorry, but this is simply wrong. Leeloo wasn't rebuilt from **the remains of a Mondoshawan**. She's been bred by the Mondoshawans and then transported in a suit which preserved some of her DNA during the crash.

Comment: @Valorum - you don't know that. However, I concede that I have no proof to support what I wrote, too. Editing accordingly.

Comment: @AcePL - Per the novel; "*General Munro studied the glove with its long tapering fingers. It looked almost human. It was certainly not as gross as he had expected it to be. “It doesn’t exactly look Mondoshawan,” he said. “Have you identified it?”*

Comment: You might wish to note that mere seconds after she was recovered, she was speaking the language of the ancients. She clearly has instant access to genetic memory.

Comment: @Valorum - What is known about Mondoshawan is next to nothing. And least of all how do they look like...  Your quote equally well proves general's possible racist (specist???) streak. Suit also proves nothing. But that's just me being devil's advocate and also a speculation. Anyway, I withdraw. Answer edited so as to no longer be controversial, nothing to be gained here ;).

Answer (score -2):

The original alien was carrying the elements to Earth (or so the bad guys thought) to give them to the priest. The bad guys blew up the alien, leaving only hand. The Earth scientists resurrected alien in the form of Leeloo. Bad guys (Mr Shadow, to be precise) have been shown to be able to spy on radio conversations, so it made sense to send alien to tell the priest where the real elements are in person, instead of giving him a call that could be intercepted and real elements taken.

Leeloo was coming to priest to tell him where the stones are. The aliens knew that the evil planet will show up soon, they probably were in contact with priests so they knew who the current priest was. Why does reconstructed Leeloo know who is current priest? Because technology to reform bodies is good enough to restore memories from partial body sample, even if the reconstructed body is that of Leeloo and not Mondoshawan body

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question : I asked how Leeloo had the priest's name, not how the priest knew where the 4 stones were

Comment: The technology to reform bodies is not what installed these memories (that's our human tech, which by the lead scientist's own admission, has never seen anything like her.)  Assuming Valorum's genetic memory theory is correct, that ability was part of her DNA and kicked in after she was reconstructed, all by itself.

Comment: True, but the original question was how Leeloo knows him. They were in contact, she was on her way to meet him, she got blown up, she was reconstructed. She still knows him. If the question was why she didn't forget, I don't know. Aliens did it! is in universe the answer to that. There won't be a movie if Bruce Willis was forced to lug around ugly alien with him is out of universe answer.